# pexpect command output truncated by columns

Tags: pexpect

The output of command `systemctl status dnsmasq` with `pexpect.spawn()` gets truncated.

```
pexpect.spawn('systemctl status dnsmasq', encoding='utf-8')
i = child.expect([".*\$ ", pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT])
if i == 1:
    child.sendcontrol("c")
print(child.before)
```

See image of output below:

[image: systemctl status dnsmasq]

I tested this for `sshd.service` and result is same. However for other commands like `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, pexpect logs full output. What's causing this behavior and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the pty size is `24x80`. Some programs would adjust their output format based on the pty size. You can explicitly set the pty size when calling `spawn()`.

```
child = pexpect.spawn('systemctl status dnsmasq', encoding='utf-8',
                      dimensions=(9999, 9999) )
                      #           rows, cols
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this attribute.